# Django template use jquery script with {{}}

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-templates

I would like use http://filer.grandesign.md/#demos but this script in query use syntax with {{ }} and django cant understand this. It's posible to give django information to leave this couple lines of code and don't try put variable there?

{{fi-image}}, {{fi-image}} etc.

**Sample code from project page:**

```
$('#filer_input').filer({
    changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-folder"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Click on this box</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">or</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn blue">Browse Files</a></div></div>',
    showThumbs: true,
    theme: "dragdropbox",
    templates: {
        box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>',
        item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                    <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                    <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                    <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                </div>\
                                {{fi-image}}\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                <ul class="list-inline pull-left"></ul>\
                                <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                    <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                </ul>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </li>',
        itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
        itemAppendToEnd: false,
        removeConfirmation: true,
        _selectors: {
            list: '.jFiler-items-list',
            item: '.jFiler-item',
            remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) tag

> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag.
>
> A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides with Django’s syntax.

```
{% verbatim %}
// code here
{% endverbatim %}
```